# Using the math library to display the sine of 1 radian rounded to three decimal points in C

Tags: c, function, trigonometry

I'm working on a small tutorial and I am a bit confused about about using the sin function. 
The purpose of this challenge is to simply use the math library to display the sine of 1 radian rounded to three decimal points. The answer should be 0.841. However, I don't know how to use the function suggested or whether or not I'm over complicating the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double sin(double x) {
  double radians = 1;
  return radians;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  printf("The sine of 1 radian is %.3d.\n, ????)");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to define your own sine function (which always just returns one)? Did you read the man page for `printf()`? Do you understand what functions are?

Comment: Yes I know what functions are and I perused the man page for the math library but not for the printf() function. It was not my choice to define my own sine function; it was instructed my the text I'm studying on Programming in C.

Comment: No, it wasn't. It was instructed that you **declare** it. A declaration is not the same thing as a definition.

Comment: Your code doesn't need `<stdlib.h>` (this time).  The `sin()` function is declared in `<math.h>` and defined in the standard C library (you might need to link with `-lm`); you should not define your own.  You do need to separate the format string from the value to be printed: `printf("%6.3f\n", sin(1.0));` or more verbosely as you require.  Note that `%…f` is for printing `double` values; `%…d` is for printing `int` values.  Printing to 3 decimal places requires a `double` (or a `float` that will be converted to `double` automatically for you by the compiler —a detail you can forget for now).

Comment: Jonathan Leffler thank you for clarifying this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't define your own (broken) `sin` function - use the one that's already in the math library:

```
printf("The sine of 1 radian is %.3f.\n", sin(1.0));
```

Comment: I wonder why the text instructed me to declare the sine function like this: double sin(double x);?? By the way the simply sin function you gave worked perfectly and was straight to the point.

Comment: The declaration just serves to tell the compiler that the (external) function exists and what its parameters are _**without defining** the body of the function itself_, but there's no need to declare the function yourself if you've done `#include <math.h>`

Comment: To clarify further, what you had in the question wasn't a function _declaration_ but a function _definition_.

Comment: It told you to *declare* the `sin` function, not to *define* it. But even that is bad advice. #include <math.h>` provides a declaration for the `sin` function.

Comment: @KeithThompson to be fair, it's probably a good idea to introduce the idea of function declarations _before_ teaching about `#include` directives...

Comment: Declaration vs definition of the function clarifies this confusion immensely for me, in  addition to the purpose of including the math.h library so that there is no need to 'define' my own sine function.

Comment: No, the `math.h` **header** _declares_ the function, and its body (i.e. its definition) is typically contained in `libm.a`